# Создание каждому пользователю сервиса своего пользователя СУБД

Tags: база-данных, сервер, веб-сервер

Пишу свой многопользовательский веб-сервер. Имеет смысл при создании пользователя сервиса создавать ему своего пользователя БД (для разграничения доступа к данным на уровне БД)? То есть каждому пользователю сервиса соответствует свой пользователь БД. Как этот подход (создание много объектов Connection) скажется на сервере при при высокой нагрузке?

Comment: Не имеет. Все разграничения доступа успешно реализует сам веб-сервер

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но хотелось бы услышать, как создание много объектов Connection скажется на сервере при большом количестве пользователей?

Comment: А как вы собрались их создавать? Правильный вариант в момент необходимости получения данных, открыли подключение, сделали запрос, закрыли подключение.